# Android Timer Alternative

Tags: android, timer

I'm looking for some timer alternative, since timer dies with app, is limited, and every timer launches own thread.
Sometimes I need to launch about 20-30 timers.

I need to set some event, in time, and when it comes display app screen. Is it possible?

Comment: I think you should use Alarmmanager. Doc is here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html and tutorials is here http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129

Comment: If you post Answer i will accept it, although both of answers satisfy me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*You should use* [AlarmManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html).

As CommonsWare says that there are some limitation of it, but that is ok, if an user force closes your application it means he doesn't want to use your application (any more or due to sort of memory)....

*And I have a solution (but may be not the best), because you can not listen if user force closes your app, so one way is that you can re schedule your event on each start of your application. I know this is not a good solution but ..... we have no any other way yet*

Here is a [good example](http://justcallmebrian.com/?p=129).

Answer (score 2):

This may or may not be possible depending upon your definition of "dies with app".

You can use `AlarmManager` to schedule `PendingIntents` to be invoked at specific times in the future. Those `PendingIntents` can launch activities. This will work if your app "dies" from ordinary causes.

However:

- If the user force-closes your app via Settings, your alarms are unscheduled, and there is nothing you can do to stop this (nor do you have any alternative to `AlarmManager` that somehow survives this)
- Please allow the user to determine whether or not you display an activity or raise a `Notification` at these times, as users may not necessarily appreciate having their game, navigation, video, or phone call interrupted by your activity.

Comment: I won't spam user, he can disable this feature. What happens to AlarmManager when app is exited by "back" or phone is restarted?

Comment: When user exits by 'back' it will work. but when restarts this will not work. You have to re schedule all events.